# QListView drop indicator styling

Tags: qt, drag-and-drop, qlistview, qtstylesheets

I am using `QListView` to show a list of items that I can drag and drop to change their order.
The problem is that:

- the drop indicator is just a very small line (1px thickness)
- the drop area is so narrow so one needs to be really accurate to drop an item correctly between two other items.

I wonder if it is possible to change the styling of the drop indicator of `QListView` so the line is thicker and the drop area is wider.

Answer (score 0):

Style of drop indicator can be changed using QStyle. `QStyle::PE_IndicatorItemViewItemDrop` enum value corresponds for it and can be used for setting style for indicator that is drawn to show where an item in an item view is about to be dropped during a drag-and-drop operation in an item view